# SVG animation bug in safari 11

Tags: animation, svg, safari

As you may know there is a new Safari released last night: Safari 11.
And this last version create a bug on SVG animation that was working fine on safari 10 or still work on chrome :

And I just don't find how to fix this, I tried everything, -webkit- subfix, container, origin etc …

Can someone have an idea ?

Here is the version that was working until the last version of Safari : https://jsfiddle.net/3f02je66/

```css
.home_st0 {fill:#FFFFFF;}
.home_st1 {fill:#6CC3BD;}
.home_st2 {fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:200;stroke-dashoffset:200;}
.home_st3 {fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:20;stroke-dashoffset:20;}
.home_st4 {fill:none;stroke:#FFFFFF;stroke-width:1.5;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-dasharray:50;stroke-dashoffset:50;}

#casserole {stroke-dasharray:200; stroke-dashoffset:200;}
#casserolePL {stroke-dasharray:20; stroke-dashoffset:20; }
#casserolePR {stroke-dasharray:20; stroke-dashoffset:20; }
#casseroleL {stroke-dasharray:50;  stroke-dashoffset:50;}
#casserole {animation: casserole .8s ease-in-out forwards .8s;}
    @keyframes casserole {
        from{stroke-dashoffset:200; }
        to {stroke-dashoffset:0;}
    }
#casserolePL {animation: casserolePL .5s ease-in-out forwards 1s;}
    @keyframes casserolePL {
        from{stroke-dashoffset:20; }
        to {stroke-dashoffset:40;}
    }
#casserolePR {animation: casserolePR .5s ease-in-out forwards 1.1s;}
    @keyframes casserolePR {
        from{stroke-dashoffset:20; }
        to {stroke-dashoffset:0;}
    }
#casseroleL {animation: casseroleL .5s ease-in-out forwards 1.2s;}
    @keyframes casseroleL {
        from{stroke-dashoffset:50; }
        to {stroke-dashoffset:100;}
    }

#aubergine {transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#aubergine {animation: aubergine 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes aubergine {
        0%{transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        20%,100% {transform: translate(45%, 400%) rotate(200deg);}
    }
#poisson {transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#poisson {animation: poisson 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes poisson {
        9%{transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        29%,100% {transform: translate(40%, 400%) rotate(-240deg);}
    }
#carotte {transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#carotte {animation: carotte 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes carotte {
        18%{transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        38%,100% {transform: translate(0%, 400%) rotate(-100deg);}
    }
#pois {transform: translate(-20%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#pois {animation: pois 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes pois {
        27%{transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        47%,100% {transform: translate(0%, 420%) rotate(160deg);}
    }
#poulet {transform: translate(-20%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#poulet {animation: poulet 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes poulet {
        36%{transform: translate(-20%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        56%,100% {transform: translate(-20%, 400%) rotate(300deg);}
    }
#feuille {transform: translate(-50%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#feuille {animation: feuille 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes feuille {
        45%{transform: translate(-40%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        65%,100% {transform: translate(15%, 400%) rotate(60deg);}
    }
#navet {transform: translate(15%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#navet {animation: navet 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes navet {
        54%{transform: translate(20%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        74%,100% {transform: translate(-35%, 460%) rotate(360deg);}
    }
#crevette {transform: translate(-15%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#crevette {animation: crevette 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes crevette {
        63%{transform: translate(-15%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        83%,100% {transform: translate(15%, 400%) rotate(-160deg);}
    }
#oignon {transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#oignon {animation: oignon 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes oignon {
        72%{transform: translate(45%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        92%,100%  {transform: translate(40%, 500%) rotate(-240deg);}
    }
#poivron {transform: translate(10%, 0%) rotate(0deg); transform-origin:center center;}
#poivron {animation: poivron 10s linear infinite 1.5s;}
    @keyframes poivron {
        81%{transform: translate(10%, 0%) rotate(0deg);}
        99%,100% {transform: translate(20%, 440%) rotate(140deg);}
    }
```

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly does not work any more? there are 14 animations listed here.

Comment: As you can see on the jsfiddle, ingredients fall inside the pot. But on safari the ingredients falls everywhere

Comment: So you think it's a webkit bug ?

Comment: Ahh, no. Safari fixed a bug. You simply coded to the bug and got bitten by that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using percentage values for `translate()` transformations. That raises the question: percentage of what?

Google Chrome and Safari 10 answer the question with ["the bounding box of the transformed element"](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#svg-user-coordinate-space). That is from the 2013 "Working Draft" of the CSS Transforms definition

Firefox and Safari 11 answer with ["the size of the local viewport"](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box). (in your case, the size of the `<svg>` element). That is from the latest "Editor's Draft" version of the CSS Transforms definition.

You could try to restore the previous behavior by setting `transform-box:fill-box`.

The better solution is not to use relative, but pixel values. Since your animated elements are all in the range of 25px width and height, dividing the current value by 4 and exchanging `%` for `px` should give you a decent start for fine-tuning these values.

Comment: The quote you are looking for is here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms/#transform-box i.e. For SVG elements without an associated CSS layout box, the used value for border-box is view-box. The other way to fix this is via transform-box: fill-box;

Comment: Thanks, I knew you would provide a source.

Comment: Okay I understand now, transform-box:fill-box was the problem. Thanks you for your help