# SVG with embedded CSS animation behaving differently between iOS10 and iOS11

Tags: css, animation, svg

I have a basic SVG log, and embedded in it I have some simple CSS animation. It's rotating an object, and making the middle of the rotation the center of the object.

It looks and works fine on Chrome / Safari in iOS10, but when you open it in iOS11 Safari the rotation is completely mad.

Can anyone help suggest why / how to fit it?

The logo can be seen here:

http://www.mediplacements.com/live2/img/logotest.svg

Comment: Safari fixed their bug about CSS bounding boxes. Chrome will follow suit soon apparently. Things rotate round the viewBox now rather than their bounding box. The transform-box property can change that in browsers that support it. Firefox supports transform-box

Answer (score 0):

When something seemingly standard work on older browsers and not in newer ones, you should check for your element's adherence to standards.
The W3C validator [indicates](https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mediplacements.com%2Flive2%2Fimg%2Flogotest.svg&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) there are 3 errors in your SVG; you should try again after fixing them.

Edit: Okay, now that it's fixed. Have you checked [SVG animation bug in safari 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327883/svg-animation-bug-in-safari-11) ?
I just tried what's suggested in the linked question, and it fixed it.
Simply add transform-box:fill-box; to your Swishes' CSS.

It tells Safari to behave like Chrome on an undecided point of the standard, namely whether transform percentage values refer to the bounding box or the parent.

FYI, the problem you describe also happens on Firefox.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was me removing stuff to see if it effected the animation or not across the different iOS versions (it didn't). I've put the code back to normal so it doesn't give any errors.